# Global bundle's routing prefix

Tags: php, symfony

I want to set a prefix for all controllers in the AdminBundle - "/admin". So I did it in routing.yml file:

```
my_admin:
   prefix: /admin
```

Then I changed all admin bundle's route names from:

```
/**
 * @Route("admin/home", name="admin/home")
 */
```

to

```
/**
 * @Route("home", name="home")
 */
```

And the problem is that when I use:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin/installation'));
```

It throws an exception that the route doesn't exist...before setting the prefix it worked. What's wrong?

Comment: what is the output of "app/console router:debug | grep admin" ?

Answer (score 0):

`Router::generateUrl` expects a route **name**, no route **path**. So if you want to link to the `home` route you showed us, you use:

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
```

The `prefix` option is about route **paths**, not about the **name** of a route.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have no route called admin/installation. Even if you have prefix for whole controller, you have to give unique names to each route.

```
/**
 * @Route("home", name="admin/home")
 */
```